# Trouble passing ViewModel to Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**My ViewModel class (ItemViewModel.cs) looks like this:**

public class ItemViewModel
{

```
public ItemViewModel(xxx.Product product)
{
    this.product = product;
}

private readonly xxx.xxx.Product product;
private readonly Pers pers;
private readonly Item item;

public xxx.xxx.Product Product
{
    get{ return product;}
}

public Item Item
{
    get { return item; }
}

public ItemList Items
{
    get { return product.Items; }
}

public Pers Pers
{
    get { return pers; }
    set { value = pers; }
}

public PersList PersList
{
    get { return product.PersList; }
}
```

}

**The view has this code defined in it** (I took out some other case lines, just to show one of them as an example):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/MasterPages/Item.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<xxx.ViewModels.ItemViewModel>" %>

    <%  foreach (Pers p in Model.Perslist)
        {
            switch(p.DispType)
            {
                case DisType.Dropdown:
                    Model.Pers = p;
                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/Controls/Custom/PForm/DropDown.ascx",*Model);
                    break;
            }
        }
    %>
```

**And the RenderPartial looks like this:**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="xxx">
        <span class="xxx">*</span><label><%=Model.Pers.Name %></label>
        <p class="xxx"><%=Model.Pers.Info %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="formField"><% Html.DropDownList(Model.Pers.Name, new SelectList(Model.Items[0].DropdownItems));%></div>
</fieldset>
```

The problem or dilemma I'm having is I not only need the p from the foreach but the entire ItemViewModel instance that was originally passed to my View.  Because I need to use the Pers in that foreach as well as be able to reference the Items.  So what I tried is to set the Pers property of the ItemViewModel class instance to the current p in the foreach.  Then tried to send the whole Model (now that I have that Pers set on the property) which is of type ItemViewModel so that I can now use the property Pers on that object and also still be able to reference the Items property that was populated already when it hit the View.

**So when the page renders I get:**

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
for this line:

```
<span class="xxx">*</span><label><%=Model.Pers.Name %></label>
```

So far I'm unsuccesful because I still get a null reference error on the property Pers when I attempt to use the ITemViewModel in my Partial View.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your partial view file needs this line above your html:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<xxx.ViewModels.**ItemViewModel**>" %>
```

So this is how your partial view should look:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<xxx.ViewModels.**ItemViewModel**>" %>
<fieldset>
    <div class="xxx">
        <span class="xxx">*</span><label><%=Model.Pers.Name %></label>
        <p class="xxx"><%=Model.Pers.Info %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="formField"><% Html.DropDownList(Model.Pers.Name, new SelectList(Model.Items[0].DropdownItems));%></div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: actually I do have that in my Partial View, the type ItemViewModel..forgot to add that I already have this.

Comment: I did have this at the top of my Partial View: <%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<xxx.ViewModels.ItemViewModel>" %>

Answer (score 0):

Good God, I set the property wrong.  resolved. duh.